# What engineer skills cause explosions?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Some traits within the "Explosives" line work only with explosions. For instance, [Steel-Packed Powder](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Steel-Packed_Powder)

> Explosions cause vulnerability for 5 seconds.

What, in this context, qualifies as an explosion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official wiki (and tested):

- [Bomb kit](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bomb_Kit)
- [Grenade Kit](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Grenade_kit)
- [Throw Mine](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Throw_Mine) with [Detonate](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Detonate)

Also qualifies (tested) :

- [Big Ol' Bomb](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Big_Ol'_Bomb)
- [Grenade barrage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Grenade_Barrage)
- [Mine Field](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mine_Field) **and** [Detonate Mine Field](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Detonate_Mine_Field) (but tricky to place)
- Bomb from [Evasive Powder Keg](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Evasive_Powder_Keg)

Explosions that do not qualifies (tested):

- Pistol's [Explosive Shot](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Explosive_Shot)
- Turret explosions as seen in [Detonate Healing Turret](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Detonate_Healing_Turret), states to ignore player's boons, traits too.
- Harpoon's [Detonate Mines](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Detonate_Mines)
- Harpoon's [Time Charge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Timed_Charge) cause it explicitly states that it causes an explosion radius.

(Test had been done with the SPP traits : if applies, it qualiifies).

Comment: Thanks so far. I was looking particularly for turret 'splosions, so I'll wait for you to finish testing!

Comment: I was able to test this myself. Detonating Turrets does not count as an explosion.

Comment: Tests have been done.